# Find and Replace HEX Strings

Tags: c#, hex, replace

OK, I'm stuck at this point... I want to compare two files and copy over(replace) the strings from one file to another.

Example File 1:

```
01cd74a8h: 65 00 00 00 54 45 53 54 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; e...TEST........
01cd74b8h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
01cd74c8h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
01cd74d8h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
01cd74e8h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 C5 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 C5 ; ...... ?..... ?
01cd74f8h: 00 00 20 45 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 45 01 00 00 00 ; .. E...... E....
01cd7508h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C9 00 00 00 54 61 6D 20 ; ........?..Tam 
01cd7518h: 54 61 20 51 75 61 6E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; Ta Quan.........
01cd7528h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
01cd7538h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
01cd7548h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 45 ; .............. E
01cd7558h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 C5 00 00 F0 45 00 00 00 00 ; ...... ?.餎....
01cd7568h: 00 00 20 45 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; .. E............
01cd7578h: 2D 01 00 00 4C 69 65 75 20 43 68 69 6E 68 20 51 ; -...Lieu Chinh Q
01cd7588h: 75 61 6E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; uan.............
01cd7598h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
01cd75a8h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
01cd75b8h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 C5 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 C5 ; ......鹋...... ?
01cd75c8h: 00 00 20 C5 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 45 01 00 00 00 ; .. ?..... E....
01cd75d8h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 91 01 00 00 56 6F 20 54 ; ........?..Vo T
01cd75e8h: 68 69 65 6E 20 43 61 63 20 31 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; hien Cac 1......
01cd75f8h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
01cd7608h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
01cd7618h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 48 C4 ; ..............H?
01cd7628h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 48 C4 00 00 48 44 00 00 00 00 ; ......H?.HD....
01cd7638h: 00 00 48 44 00 00 00 00 10 CA 9A 3B 00 00 00 00 ; ..HD.....蕷;....
```

Example File 2:

```
01b954a8h: 65 00 00 00 43 65 6E 74 72 61 6C 20 56 61 6C 6C ; e...Central Vall
01b954b8h: 65 79 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ey..............
01b954c8h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
01b954d8h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
01b954e8h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 C5 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 C5 ; ...... ?..... ?
01b954f8h: 00 00 20 45 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 45 01 00 00 00 ; .. E...... E....
01b95508h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C9 00 00 00 48 69 6C 6C ; ........?..Hill
01b95518h: 20 56 61 6C 6C 65 79 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ;  Valley.........
01b95528h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
01b95538h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
01b95548h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 45 ; .............. E
01b95558h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 C5 00 00 F0 45 00 00 00 00 ; ...... ?.餎....
01b95568h: 00 00 20 45 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; .. E............
01b95578h: 2D 01 00 00 52 69 76 65 72 73 69 64 65 20 50 6C ; -...Riverside Pl
01b95588h: 61 69 6E 73 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ains............
01b95598h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
01b955a8h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
01b955b8h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 C5 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 C5 ; ......鹋...... ?
01b955c8h: 00 00 20 C5 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 45 01 00 00 00 ; .. ?..... E....
01b955d8h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 91 01 00 00 46 6F 72 62 ; ........?..Forb
01b955e8h: 69 64 64 65 6E 20 54 6F 77 65 72 20 31 46 00 00 ; idden Tower 1F..
01b955f8h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
01b95608h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
01b95618h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 48 C4 ; ..............H?
01b95628h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 48 C4 00 00 48 44 00 00 00 00 ; ......H?.HD....
01b95638h: 00 00 48 44 00 00 00 00 10 CA 9A 3B 00 00 00 00 ; ..HD.....蕷;....
```

What I want to do is compare File1 to File2, to see if there are any matches in the Item ID's, and copy over File2's information to File1, ONLY if the item exists.

The Item ID starts 4 bytes behind the Item name.

```
  01b954a8h: 65 00 00 00 43 65 6E 74 72 61 6C 20 56 61 6C 6C ; e...Central Vall
  01b954b8h: 65 79 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ey..............

  01b95508h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C9 00 00 00 48 69 6C 6C ; ........?..Hill
  01b95518h: 20 56 61 6C 6C 65 79 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ;  Valley.........
```

Here you can see that "65 00" and "C9 00" are the ID for Central Valley and Hill Valley correspondingly.

Comment: I tried doing this in a really ugly way...
Loaded item IDs and Names into listbox and compared and replaced but it consumes a lot of memory and the performance is poor.

Answer (score 1):

To me it's not clear why you want to do this in Hex.  It seems like you can just deal with it as text.

My thought is that you should look toward using a Regular Expression to find whitespace delimited words and back up a couple of characters to get the ID characters (which can then be converted to hex if you so need).

Comment: Might not necesarily need to be hex it cuold be as a byte array, but the text doesn't read the null bytes "00".

Comment: @AlanAlvarez Using byte arrays would be fine, and would probably be faster than strings, but there is no reason why you couldn't use strings if you wanted to.  As you load the data into memory, simply decode them into a string, and encode them when you write them back out.  When you write it back out you'd have to pad the data, of course, with null characters.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading the items into a list box, load the items into two Dictionary objects (where the integer is the item's ID, and the string is the item's description.  Load one dictionary per file.  Then compare the items in the dictionary, make whatever modifications you need to make to the one dictionary, then save it back out to the file.